# JSON to JavaScript object #text property

Tags: javascript, json, eval, hashtag

I am currently developing a JavaScript add-on which receives JSON from an API. So far, so good I retrieve the JSON and then use `eval()` to convert this JSON to a JavaScript object. This is where the problems start.

My JSON contains a '#text'-property. I evaluated the JavaScript object and found it also has this '#text'-property, but I can not call the property since variables with hash-tags are not accepted.

I know two possible solutions (use `eval()` to convert to an Array or remove the hast-tag), but I would prefer calling the property. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use eval unless you have to. Despite being a slower solution, it's less safe, especially considering there are usually so many native JSON methods. Secondly, please clarify your question, since a property named `#blah` is entirely valid.

Comment: You can also do something like: `var textName = '#text'; alert(obj[textName]);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use eval, especially for this. You a json parser, modern browsers already have them.

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(returnFromServer);
console.log(myObj.firstProperty); // etc
```

Here's a CDN link for json2 http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

Answer (score 9):

You can reference object properties with square brackets:

```
var obj = {'#foo': 'bar'};
obj['#foo']; // 'bar'
```

Indeed, `obj.#foo` is invalid (i.e. will raise a syntax error), but the above method is fine.

Also, don't use eval unless you have to. Despite being a slower solution, it's less safe, especially considering there are usually so many native JSON methods, and most JSON libraries will introduce the functionality *only* if the native methods don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Do stuff before eval like replacing hash sign with something else.